# How to create a map function in c++?

Tags: c++, list, dictionary

Say there is a list of integers [1,2,3,4,5] and a map function that multiplies each element with 10 and returns modified list as [10,20,30,40,50] , with out modifying the original list.
How this can be done efficiently in c++.

Comment: Sorry...I have used transform and for_each, could not recollect it at the moment, I was looking for fourth parameter in for_each thinking that as transform :(

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int multiply(int);

int main() {
    vector<int> source;
    for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    source.push_back(i);
    }

    vector<int> result;
    result.resize(source.size());
    transform(source.begin(), source.end(), result.begin(), multiply);

    for(vector<int>::iterator it = result.begin(); it != result.end(); ++it) {
        cout << *it << endl;
    }
}

int multiply(int value) {
    return value * 10;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Along the lines of @darids answer, but C++03 (current at the time of original post):

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

std::vector<int> src;
std::vector<int> dst;

std::transform(src.begin(), src.end(),
               std::back_inserter(dst),
               std::bind1st(std::multiplies<int>(), 10));
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  I suggest adding the necessary include directives for clarity.

Comment: Current C++ would be to use a lambda instead of bind1st.

Comment: @sv90 for sure, time and C++ have moved on since I posted this answer!

Answer (score 4):

If you can use it, probably the best idea is to use a function in the Standard Template Library.

For example, you might want to check out [for_each](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/) or [transform](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/), which basically do just that.

Answer (score 4):

I only post this to illustrate using a functor in transform rather than a global function:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct MulBy : public std::unary_function<int, int>
{
    MulBy(int v) : v_(v) {}
    int operator()(int lhs) const
    {
        return lhs * v_;
    }
private:
    int v_;
};

int main()
{
    int incoming[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int result[5] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    transform(&incoming[0], &incoming[5], &result[0], MulBy(10));
    copy(&result[0], &result[5], ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   #include <iostream>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <vector>
    #include <functional>
    using namespace std;

    struct MulBy : public std::unary_function<int, int>
    {
        MulBy(int v) : v_(v) {}
        int operator()(int lhs) const
        {
            return lhs * v_;
        }
    private:
        int v_;
    };
    int main()
    {
        vector<int> ListOfNumber;
        ListOfNumber.push_back(1);
        ListOfNumber.push_back(2);
        ListOfNumber.push_back(3);
        ListOfNumber.push_back(4);
        ListOfNumber.push_back(5);
        vector<int> ListResult;
        ListResult.resize(ListOfNumber.size());

        //Produces a new list
        transform(ListOfNumber.begin(),ListOfNumber.end(),ListResult.begin(),MulBy(10));
     copy(ListOfNumber.begin(),ListOfNumber.end(),ostream_iterator<int>(cout,"\t"));
        //Modifies the original list
    transform(ListOfNumber.begin(),ListOfNumber.end(),ListOfNumber.begin(),MulBy(10));
    copy(ListResult.begin(),ListResult.end(),ostream_iterator<int>(cout,"\t"));
        cin.get();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my implementation for an array map method, inspired directly from javascript

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
namespace wh{
    namespace array{
      
      template<typename T>
      std::vector<T> map(const std::vector<T> &vectorToMap, const std::function<T(T)> &functor){
          std::vector<T> ret;
          for(auto &element: vectorToMap){
              ret.push_back(functor(element));
          }
          return ret;
      }

      ...
    }
}



#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    //'spray', 'limit', 'elite', 'exuberant', 'destruction', 'present'
    std::vector<std::string> words = {"spray", "limit", "elite", "exuberant", "destruction", "present", "windows", "wlol"};}

    // and this is how it is used:
    words = wh::array::map<std::string>(words, [](auto word){return word+"l";});
    
    for(auto &word: words) std::cout << word << std::endl;
    

    return 0;
}
```

Maybe this will be useful for someone else, still, if `<algorithm>` functions are a better approach, go ahead and use them.